# Generate a hash value from two strings where I could use either of them to find the value I am looking for

Tags: c++, hash, hashtable

I am currently trying to implement hash table that stores pointers to objects containing information about certain stocks. The problem is that my implementation has to be able to return the same hash value from two different strings which are the full name of a stock (eg. Apple) and its ticker symbol (eg AAPL) respectively. Of course, I could simply create two seperatd hash tables for each of them but I believe there has to be a better solution for this.

On a side note, I am using C++ and still fairly inexperienced, so I am not sure if I should use an initial size st::vector or a std::array for my hash table. Is there an advantage of using one over the other?

Comment: I think your question is not clear. However, if you do not need to modify the elements once inserted (they can be const), you may use the standard container `std::unordered_set`, storing the two elements together as `std::pair`.

Comment: On the other hand, there are many differences between `std::array` and `std::vector`, and they are well described in the following post: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/difference-between-std-vector-and-std-array-in-cplusplus.